# How to use multiple tree-sitter parsers in buffer

Tags: tree-sitter

How does one use local treesit parsers/multiple parsers to fontify different regions in a buffer?  I haven't been able to find any tree-sitter modes that are currently using local parsers to see how it is supposed to work.

According to `treesit-local-parsers-on`, if I'm reading it correctly, I should be able to specify local parsers by adding a `treesit-parser` property to an overlay.  The doc also says the local parsers should have an `embedded` tag. So, I've tried doing that, eg. in a `dockerfile-ts-mode` buffer

```
RUN          \
    # comment
    echo foo \
    bar
```

Adding an overlay with a `treesit-parser` for `bash` to the body of the `RUN` command (with region selected),

```
(let ((ov (make-overlay (region-beginning) (region-end))))
  (overlay-put
   ov 'treesit-parser
   (treesit-parser-create 'bash nil nil 'embedded)))
```

But, I'm not sure what to do next - calling `treesit-font-lock-fontify-region` doesn't seem to do anything with the bash parser.

Anyone know how to get multiple parsers working together? And if so, is there a way to specify regions to be injected with local parsers in the `treesit-font-lock-rules`?

[[it looks like [nvim-treesitter](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/blob/master/queries/dockerfile/injections.scm) has a nice mechanism to handle this]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read [chapter 37.6 Parsing Text in Multiple Languages](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Multiple-Languages.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual? It gives plenty of details and even some examples.

Specifically, you should call `treesit-parser-set-included-ranges` to set up the embedded parser instead of creating an overlay directly. Alternatively you can call `treesit-range-rules` to turn queries into embedded parsers automatically.

Comment: Thankyou! `treesit-range-rules` looks perfect, I'm dumb missing that section - it's actually much more tutorial-like than a lot of the manual - super useful